# Creating a variable-length list of integral equations using a loop

Tags: list-manipulation, numerical-integration

I need to automatically form a list of equations that later will be used in `FindRoot`. The number of equations (NN) is variable, so I need to use a For loop. When I am doing this

```
LstEqns = {}; For[i = 1, i <= NN, i++,
  LstEqns = 
  Append[LstEqns,
   NIntegrate[Eq[i], {x, 0, L}] == 0];
 ];
```

I am getting a warning that `L` is not a valid limit of integration (the value is not provided at this point) and in the list I am not getting `i` substituted by its proper values, i.e. `LstEqns` looks like `{NIntegrate[Eq[i], {x, 0, L}] == 0,...}` instead of `{NIntegrate[Eq[1], {x, 0, L}] == 0,...}`.
The value of L is provided later (as well as actual  `Eq[i]`), after forming the list.
So the question is - how can I get a list of equations with a proper numbering?
Mathematica 11.3 is what I am using if this matters.

**UPD**

```
n = 1;
LstEqns2 := 
  Inactive[NIntegrate][#[[1]], {x, 0, L}] == 0 & /@ Transpose[{eqns2}];
eqns2 = Array[Eq, n];
theEqns2 = LstEqns2;
Eq[1] = x*y + 1;
L = 1;

FindRoot[theEqns2, {y, 0}, Evaluated -> False]
```

- doesn't work ("The function value is not a list of numbers")

Manually copying the output of theEqns2 into FindRoot doesn't work either:

```
FindRoot[Inactive[NIntegrate][x*y + 1, {x, 0, L}], {y, 0}, 
 Evaluated -> False]
```

- same error

However, the same line as above will work if I delete inactive NIntegrate (that has a different color in Mathematica) and placeholder and then write NIntegrate again

```
FindRoot[NIntegrate[x*y + 1, {x, 0, L}] == 0, {y, 0}, 
 Evaluated -> False]
```

- this code works

Comment: First, don't use capital ``N`` as a variable because it has a [predefined meaning](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html) in Mathematica. Second, use [`Hold`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hold.html) or [`Inactive`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive.html), for example: ``Hold@NIntegrate[Eq[i], {x, 0, L}]`` or ``Inactive[NIntegrate][Eq[i], {x, 0, L}]``.

Comment: I edited the question. It wasn't really N in my code, I used N here for simplicity and forgot that it is reserved

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Whenever you think that you "need" a `For` loop, you probably don't.

```
LstEqns := Inactive[NIntegrate][#, {x, 0, L}] == 0 & /@ eqns
```

Note that what you are labeling `Eq[i]` are not equations but rather expressions. Since they will be the integrand and will later be the LHS of an equation, they should not have a `Head` of `Equal`

```
n = RandomInteger[{1, 10}]

(* 5 *)

eqns = Array[Eq, n]

(* {Eq[1], Eq[2], Eq[3], Eq[4], Eq[5]} *)

theEqns = LstEqns
```

[image]

**EDIT:** If the RHS of the equations aren't zero

```
n = RandomInteger[{1, 10}]

(* 6 *)

LstEqns2 := 
 Inactive[NIntegrate][#[[1]], {x, 0, L}] == #[[2]] & /@ 
  Transpose[{eqns2, rhs}]

eqns2 = Array[Eq, n];

rhs = Array[RightPart, n];

theEqns2 = LstEqns2
```

[image]

**EDIT 2:** For the revised question

```
n = 1;
LstEqns2 := 
  Inactive[NIntegrate][#[[1]], {x, 0, L}] == 0 & /@ Transpose[{eqns2}];
eqns2 = Array[Eq, n];
theEqns2 = LstEqns2;
Eq[1] = x*y + 1;
L = 1;
```

`theEqns2` must be activated; and since `FindRoot` has the attribute `HoldAll`, you must `Evaluate` the first argument, i.e.,

```
FindRoot[Evaluate[theEqns2 // Activate], {y, 0}, Evaluated -> False] // Quiet

(* {y -> -2.} *)
```

Comment: Thank you. What modifications there will be needed if Integral[Eq[i]] is equal not to zero by to some RightPart[i]?

Comment: Thanks, this forms the equation set. However, FindRoot with theEqns2 plugged in doesn't work - probably, because NIntegrate is inactive. What is the proper way to activate it? Just Activate[theEqns2] doesn't work

Comment: Have you defined `L` and the vectors? Without seeing your code I cannot say why it doesn’t work as you expect.

Comment: Yes, everything is defined. Using formed as shown in the example theEqns2 doesn't work in FindRoot. Copypasted set of equations {...} doesn't work either - NIntegrate is inactive (has a different color). If, however, I manually delete the inactive NIntegrate command and the placeholder appearing after that and write NIntegrate once again, the equations work in FindRoot

Comment: No `Inactive` function will evaluate until you `Activate` it. I cannot work with a vague description of code. Post a question with the actual code for a minimal example that shows what you have tried.

Comment: I updated the question with code